# Trigger will not insert using data from another instance\DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-trigger

I am trying to run an insert trigger when a new record gets created. This record will use data from another instance\DB to insert on another table. I am able to insert running it as a query but as a trigger it will not fire or insert. I am looking for some ideas as to why. Thanks!

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TriggerName]
   ON  [dbo].[Table] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH batch AS (
        SELECT              b.uniqueid
                            ,CASE WHEN b.versionnumber LIKE '%SOMETHING%' THEN '1' + SUBSTRING(REPLACE(bh.pvalue,'MIXER_',''),1,1) ELSE SUBSTRING(REPLACE(bh.pvalue,'SOMETHING',''),1,1) END AS MIXER


        FROM                inserted b
          INNER JOIN        table1 bh ON b.uniqueid = bh.Uniqueid

        WHERE               bh.DescriptAPI = 'Alias_mixer_class'
    )

    INSERT INTO BATCH_TRACKING
    (ORDER_ID, BATCH_ID, DATE_CREATED)

    SELECT          o.ORDER_ID
                    ,b.uniqueid
                    ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

    FROM            [INSTANCE\DB].ProdOrchTest.dbo.table3 o
      INNER JOIN    batch b on o.LINE_NUM = b.MIXER

    WHERE           o.LINE_POSITION = 0

END
```

Comment: To debug, remove the `SET NOCOUNT ON` so you get the number of selected rows inside the trigger when inserting from SSMS. Also, copy the first `SELECT` statement to get the number of "batch" records. Besides, I prefer to create synonyms for all remote tables, and reference them in code only by the synonym.

Comment: The select statement only returns one record always and I did remove the no count while trying the synonym but did not do anything

Comment: Start with basic debugging - because we have no idea what your system looks like  nor how you are validating this. Take the query you have out and put it into a single script. Add a table variable that contains at least 2 rows with existing values for uniqueid. Remove the insert and replace inserted with your table variable. Run it and verify. If that works, then how are you causing the trigger to fire?

Comment: It's almost always a bad idea to have a trigger access any resources outside of its own *database*, let alone instance. If there are, say, any network issues temporarily affecting access to the remote instance, then you've just broken insert on this table

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a linked server to get the remote data? otherwise you will not be able to query remote data.

Comment: Yes. This has been done and is in use with other databases

Comment: but are you getting any issue? you can query sys.dm_exec_trigger_stats and see if your trigger has been fired or not.